# Highcharts rendering is taking lot of time in IE11

Tags: jquery, highcharts

I am trying to render data onto the graph using highcharts. I have more than 100 charts to be rendered, each chart having 3 to 4 series lines with 30 data points.when I am rendering for the first 2 3 charts it's taking less amount of time but from 4th or 5th graph it's taking lot of time to render on to the chart not sure why. But it's taking quite less amount of time in chrome. Could you please help me out in this

Comment: Hi @kavya, Have you tried to optimize the rendering process? You can try to disable animation or for example render only visible charts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set in the head section

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
```

Also check the document type to be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I have this code already but still having the performance issues